# Cloth Physics not Working after apply

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

i have made a female charackter and i will add Physics to the breast of the charackter. it's working fine but when i apply the cloth physics the physics object to simulate the breast physics will not move any more and the SurfaceDeform that i use to follow the breast physics object movement are not moving to, also when i apply the SurfaceDeform the brest go to the left and will also not move with the breast physics object

Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v0MarpcC3JaH3J4ryZFaFSda-NzauCjD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: When you say apply, you mean apply a modifier? Then that's normal. Applying a modifier effectively bakes the mesh as it is when you apply the modifier. Don't apply it if you don't want that.

Comment: In Blender, "Apply" kinda means "*bake the changes to the mesh and delete the modifier*". There's some vertex weight or surface deform trickery you can employ if you need to get rid of the cloth physics but keep the deformations, but unless your PC's having a hard time, probably easier to leave the modifiers running